# Relationship between canonical commutation relations and projective representations?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, c-star-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\CCR{CCR}\DeclareMathOperator\Im{Im}\DeclareMathOperator\PU{PU}$Let $V$ be a real vector space equipped with an antisymmetric bilinear form $\omega$. Recall that there is a $C^\ast$ algebra
$$\CCR(V,\omega)$$
(for "canonical commutation relations") freely generated by elements
$$\{W(f) \mid f \in V\}$$
subject to the relations

1. $W(-f) = W(f)^\ast$ and
2. $W(f)W(g) = e^{i\omega(f,g)} W(g)W(f)$

Let $\pi: \CCR(V,\omega) \to B(H)$ be a representation of $\CCR(V,\omega)$ on a Hilbert space $H$. Then from (1) and (2) we see that $\pi$ induces a projective unitary representation of $V$ on $H$, i.e., a group homomorphism $V \to \PU(H)$, where $V$ is considered as a group under addition.

**Question:** Let $\phi: V \to \PU(H)$ be a projective representation of the additive group of a real vector space $V$ (perhaps satisfying some continuity conditions?). Then does there exist an antisymmetric form $\omega$ on $V$ such that $\phi$ arises from a representation of $\CCR(V,\omega)$ on $H$ (perhaps with corresponding continuity conditions)?

**Background:**

My understanding is that in physics, one is interested in the case where $V$ is the underlying real vector space of a Hilbert space which serves as the state space for a single particle of some sort, with $\omega(f,g) = \Im \langle f,g \rangle$; in this case there is an interesting representation of $\CCR(V,\omega)$ on the bosonic Fock space associated to $V$ from which free field operators and creation 
/ annihilation operators are constructed.

Comment: $\def\Z{\mathbb Z}\def\R{\mathbb R}$Am I right in re-formulating the question as:  $\phi$ canonically gives $\overline\omega_\phi : V \otimes_{\Z} V \to \R/2\pi i\Z$ (essentially the cocycle realising the obstruction to liftability), and you're wondering under what conditions this may be lifted to $\omega : V \otimes_{\Z} V \to \R$ that factors through $V \otimes_{\Z} V \to V \otimes_{\R} V$?  (EDIT:  I guess the re-formulation doesn't matter, in light of @FrancoisZiegler's comment.)

Comment: Yes, to an extent. See Baggett-Kleppner ([1973](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=51:791)) whose Introduction starts: “The classification of the irreducible multiplier representations of a real vector group is an easy consequence of the Stone-von Neumann theorem. With no loss of generality one may assume that the multiplier is the exponential of an alternating bilinear form.” (And they go on to generalize to “quite arbitrary locally compact abelian groups.” That includes discrete [no continuity condition] but not $\infty$-dimensional topological vector groups...)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler, I appreciate your re-posting the edited [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357575/relationship-between-canonical-commutation-relations-and-projective-representati#comment899028_357575) so that I look [prophetic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357575/relationship-between-canonical-commutation-relations-and-projective-representati#comment899026_357575).

Comment: I am very predictable :-)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Thanks! For the finite-dimensional case, I'm having trouble seeing how this follows from the Stone-von Neumann theorem. Is it as obvious as they indicate? Regarding infinite dimensions, perhaps I need to be a bit more precise in my question, but I am interested in this case. The Stone-von Neumann theorem isn't available here.

Comment: If you have access to the paper, their argument for $\mathbf R^n$ is on p. 314 with reference to Kleppner ([1965](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0135.06604)).